# CrossTab Headache for a Simple Table

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I have a MSSQL Server table that looks like this :

[image]

and i want it to look like this on Crystal report 10 :

[image]

I have been trying everything i know with Cross-tabs but its not giving me this. Please i need help with this.

N.B
This is supposed to be in a right section of the report. The report itself is a big spreadsheet that contains different information. So i need to have this grid-like table at a section and not on entire report.

Answer (score 0):

No need to summarize detail records, so no need for CrossTab?

The result set already has the info you need. So place the column headers in report header, detail in detail section, and summary in report footer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The report is like a spreadsheet and has other info. That section is supposed to be just a part of the report and so i need to have it in a grid-like table at a part of the report

Comment: @TobyyDamian you could create the grid structure yourself on the report.  There are 2 ways to do this.  One is to size your fields so that their edges touch, then enable borders on the fields.  The other method is to use the drawing tools to create vertical and horizontal lines where they are needed.

Comment: @R.McMillan Thanks. The row structure is not fixed. Sometimes the rows in the table could be 2, sometimes 5 or sometimes even 7. If i use grid structure as suggested, would it also be dynamic ? Having it static wont work. I want to design that section of report to be dynamic with number of rows in the table and still display in the exact structure as the picture in the post.

Comment: If you draw a line object in a section, or place borders around a data field within a section, those lines/borders will repeat as often as the section repeats, which makes the grid structure fairly dynamic.  This does require that you size the section so that there is no space above or below that would be repeated and create gaps.  If you need further help with this, it might be more useful to start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to isolate that area of the report, Insert a Subreport.

Detail section in any report repeats for each row in result set. So, yes, this approach is dynamic.